# What is the significance of the name "Brandon" Stark?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

There are many Brandon Starks through the years.  Some of the ones we know about are [listed here](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brandon_Stark_%28disambiguation%29)

What is the significance of the name "Brandon"?  House Stark was supposedly founded by Bran "the Builder", so it could be people naming their kids after the founder of the House, but I don't see a bunch of "Lann Lannisters" running around.

Comment: No comments about the many historically significant Brandons?  Ned's brother indirectly starting Robert's rebellion, the night king, Bran the builder, and now Bran with his green sight.

Answer (score 10):

I thought the name Brandon Stark was a tribute to Eddard's Brother and a tribute to his ancestors. The name Brandon means prince and brave in Irish, and the latest Brandon is indeed a Prince and is probably going to be brave. Also in the Game of Throne books people name people and things after dead people that they liked. Like when Danaerys names her dragons after her husband and brother. Also when she named her unborn child after her oldest brother Rhaegar.
Another thing is that the current Brandon is probably going to become the builder of his house Stark. Since everyone else is dead. He is probably going to bring his family together and build the Starks back into a strong family.

Comment: Interesting info about the Irish meaning!  Good observation about Bran "building" the Stark family back as well

Comment: Interesting notes on the name, though a source would be nice. I do not share your belief about "our" Brandon, I think that the little brother, Rickon, will be the one to rebuild house Stark. I'll leave out the reason why, as it is quite spoiler-ish.

Comment: http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/brandon    This link is from a site, but I think any name meaning site will do. There are other meanings to his name though. This link is to a site that tells the meaning of "Brandon".

Comment: "Another thing is that the current Brandon is probably going to become the builder of his house Stark. Since everyone else is dead. He is probably going to bring his family together and build the Starks back into a strong family." that's a really interesting idea, what makes you think that? I'm finding it hard to envision given where Bran currently is in the books, and where he appears to be headed... I don't see how your theory would work. Also, there are other Stark children still alive...

Comment: Okay I really like what your saying. I mean look at the characters I personally think that the House Stark is going be rebuilt. Analyze the characters: Arya- she is more like a fighter and is more hands on. Sansa- is more like a catelyn character and is still finding her strength. Rickon is to small and is probably going to have a Rob  sort of role. Brandon wanted to be a knight but now he is learning to use his powers. He is probably going to find his family using his powers and using all of their collective talents help save their family. Everyone is lost they need a beacon, he is that.

Comment: Haha, reading this now, @TLP's reasoning was... off.  :p

Comment: @JesseWilliams That's the tv-show. Half of westeros died there last season. Brandon is crippled and perhaps cannot have children, and in the books, Davos is sent out to get him and bring him to White Harbour.

Answer (score 2):

Both Starks and Lannisters honour their founders in their names. Whereas the Starks often name one boy on each generation Brandon in honour of Bran the builder, the Lannisters simply incorporated the the name Lann into their surnames.

Comment: Where did you get this information? Its the first time I hear of this naming tradition, and I've read all the books.

Comment: If you look at the known Stark family trees, Brandon is by far the most common name, with at least one Brandon each generation. The fact that the legendary founder of House Stark is called Brandon makes the connection obvious. The surname Lannister is derived from the name Lann, plus the sufix -ster, as in Worcester or Winchester in English are.

Comment: It could also be a sign of them naming a son after a loved relative, such as with Ned naming his son Brandon after his brother who died. Or a coincidence. If this is a deduction of yours, you should state it as such, and not as a fact. It is a well reasoned motivation, so you should include it.

Comment: Fair enough. But my point was that even if Bran (son of Eddard) has that name in honour of Brandon (son of Rickard), the reason the latter has that name in the first place is because of Bran the Builder.

Comment: My point is that this is your theory, not a fact from the books. And you have stated it as though it were the latter, not the former. It is not a bad theory, but you have presented it wrong, and you could improve your answer by adding the reasoning you have mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Lann the Clever was not a Lannister by birth. He founded the House. andrepd is correct that Lannisters incorporated the name on their surnames because we can imply it from the text

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider:

1) The founder of House Stark is the mythical Bran the Builder. Bran is short for Brandon. Other noble houses are prone to name their children after their founder. Notice the several dozen Aegon Targaryens in history.

2) Other Northern houses seem to use the name Brandon as well, so it would seem that the name Brandon is common enough, at least in the North.

So combine those two observations together and it's not so surprising that there are several Brandon Starks.

Answer (score 1):

In real life people name their children after family members, celebrities, people they admire and book characters all the time. The next time a high profile celebrity couple has a child just look at the boost in baby names of their child's name.

Also note as with many families, at least those I know of in the UK, names are passed down through the generations. My first name is a name passed down through all known generations on my dad's side and my middle name is a name that comes from my granddad on my mum's side (it could even go further than that but I'm not sure).

With this in mind let's have a look at why Brandon is a popular name in House Stark.

#### Brandon the Builder

Legend has it that Brandon the Builder is the founder of House Stark, raised Winterfell, the Wall, Storm's End and a 200 foot tower in Oldtown; though the tower may have been designed by his son Brandon.

> The greatest castle of the North is Winterfell, the seat of the Starks since the Dawn Age. Legend says that **Brandon the Builder raised Winterfell** after the generation-long winter known as the Long Night to become the stronghold of his descendants, the Kings of Winter. As Brandon the Builder is connected with an improbable number of great works (**Storm's End and the Wall**, to name but two prominent examples) over a span of numerous lifetimes, the tales have likely turned some ancient king, or a number of different kings of House Stark **(for there have been many Brandons in the long reign of that family)** into something more legendary.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The North: Winterfell</sub>

> That tower, we are told, rose two hundred feet above the harbor. Some say it was designed by Brandon the Builder, whilst others name his son, another Brandon; the king who demanded it, and paid for it, is remembered as Uthor of the High Tower.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The Reach: Oldtown</sub>

Brandon the Builder allegedly also gave the lands south of the Wall to the Night's Watch though again this could have been another Brandon.

> "The Night's Watch," he answered. "This is the Gift. The New Gift, and north of that Brandon's Gift." Maester Luwin had taught him the history. "Brandon the Builder gave all the land south of the Wall to the black brothers, to a distance of twenty-five leagues. For their . . . for their sustenance and support." He was proud that he still remembered that part. "Some maesters say it was some other Brandon, not the Builder, but it's still Brandon's Gift. Thousands of years later, Good Queen Alysanne visited the Wall on her dragon Silverwing, and she thought the Night's Watch was so brave that she had the Old King double the size of their lands, to fifty leagues. So that was the New Gift." He waved a hand. "Here. All this."
>   <sub>A Storm of Swords, Bran III</sub>

#### Brandon the Shipwright and Brandon the Burner

Both are members of House Stark the Shipwright loved the sea and tried to cross the Sunset Sea but was lost to it. After his father failed to return the Burner set light to the Stark's ships and ended their power at sea.

> That's a Brandon, the tall one with the dreamy face, he was Brandon the Shipwright, because he loved the sea. His tomb is empty. He tried to sail west across the Sunset Sea and was never seen again. His son was Brandon the Burner, because he put the torch to all his father's ships in grief.
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Bran VII</sub>

#### Brandon Stark Son of Rickard Stark

Perhaps the most obvious but this is Eddard's brother and Bran's uncle and who perhaps Bran is named after. Especially as Brandon's life was cut short due to the Mad King.

> "And there's my grandfather, Lord Rickard, who was beheaded by Mad King Aerys. His daughter Lyanna and his son Brandon are in the tombs beside him. Not me, another Brandon, my father's brother. They're not supposed to have statues, that's only for the lords and the kings, but my father loved them so much he had them done."
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Bran VII</sub>

#### Brandon the Daughterless

Another legend, amongst the Free Folk, of a Lord Brandon Stark.

> "This was **Brandon the Daughterless**," Ygritte said sharply. "Would you hear the tale, or no?"
>   He scowled. "Go on."
>   "Lord Brandon had no other children. At his behest, the black crows flew forth from their castles in the hundreds, but nowhere could they find any sign o' Bael or this maid. For most a year they searched, till the lord lost heart and took to his bed, and **it seemed as though the line o' Starks was at its end.** But one night as he lay waiting to die, Lord Brandon heard a child's cry. He followed the sound and found his daughter back in her bedchamber, asleep with a babe at her breast."
>   <sub>A Clash of Kings, Jon VI</sub>

#### Brandon of the Bloody Blade

Another legend Brandon where Brandon the Builder is said to have descended from.

> The list is long, and many are the legends, for there is scarce a noble house in all the Reach that does not boast of descent from one of Garth Greenhand's countless children. Even the heroes of other lands and kingdoms are sometimes numbered amongst the offspring of the Greenhand. **Brandon the Builder was descended from Garth by way of Brandon of the Bloody Blade**, these tales would have us believe, whilst Lann the Clever was a bastard born to Florys the Fox in some tales or Rowan Gold-Tree in others.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The Reach: Garth Greenhand</sub>

#### Brandon the Bad

> Their footsteps echoed through the cavernous crypts. The shadows behind them swallowed his father as the shadows ahead retreated to unveil other statues; no mere lords, these, but the old Kings in the North. On their brows they wore stone crowns. Torrhen Stark, the King Who Knelt. Edwyn the Spring King. Theon Stark, the Hungry Wolf. **Brandon the Burner and Brandon the Shipwright.** Jorah and Jonos, **Brandon the Bad**, Walton the Moon King, Edderion the Bridegroom, Eyron, Benjen the Sweet and Benjen the Bitter, King Edrick Snowbeard.
>   <sub>A Clash of Kings, Bran VII</sub>

#### King Brandon Stark

Another Brandon and this one forced the stoneborn back onto Skagos and destroyed their naval power. Note that the quote also includes ninth of his name meaning there are even more who aren't commented on.

> Though rarely seen off their island, the stoneborn once were accustomed to crossing the Bay of Seals to trade or, more oft, raid—until **King Brandon Stark, Ninth of His Name,** broke their power once and for all, destroyed their ships, and forbade them the sea.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The North: The Stoneborn of Skagos</sub>

I'm sure there are even more historical Brandon's but I think you get the idea by now.

Comment: On your Dad's side you come from a long line of The's, and your maternal grandfather was called Lethal?

Comment: @user14111 Spot on

Answer (score 0):

The first and most important Brandon was **Brandon the Builder**. He was the one who built **Winterfell** as well as **The Wall**. ( A Game of Thrones, Chapter 24, Bran ).

He was the one that helped the (then) seven Kingdoms safe from giants and the other threats of the North. So, a lot of people were grateful to him.

Apart from him, I don't remember anyone else who was as important as him with the name Brandon